# How to get AD group name from description

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I am trying to get AD group name from the description. I was using the following command but it doesn't seems to work. Could anyone share if they have a better way to do it?

```
Get-ADGroup -filter {description -like "t:\xxx\yyy"} | select name,distinguishedname
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by it doesn't work? Do you get an error code or do you get no results? Can you provide an example of exactly what you're looking for and what the group description is?

First thing which comes to mind after looking at your code, is the t:\xxx\yyy in the quotes an exact match for what's in the description, or is it just part of the description? If it's only part, you'll need wildcards or a regular expression to select the rest of the text.

Example:

`Get-ADGroup -Filter {description -like "*t:\xxx\yyy*"} | select name,distinguishedname`

Comment: I got no errors but there was no results. And yes, the t:xxx\yyy is the exact match. AD group name: XXXYYY. Description t:\xxx\yyy

Comment: @Anjana - I don't know, the command works as written as long as there are group descriptions which contain the text in the filter. If there are no group descriptions containing the text, the result will be an empty set. I'm assuming you're running PS using credentials which has access to view AD groups. It's hard to say without knowing more about your environment and what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: I copied the exact description and tried with the code :Get-ADGroup -Filter {description -like "t:\xxx\yyy"} | select name,distinguishedname. It didn't give me any result(no error). And I am sure I have access to AD using PS. for eg: I could fetch AD group name with all other attributes(eg: cn,extension attributes etc) but not with description.

Comment: Hi @Anjana, can you try with this as the description "*xxx\yyy*"

Comment: Hi @LachieWhite and Ash Housewares, I could get it work if my description doesnt have special characters like "\". if my description is "XXX" it works. If my description is "xxx\yyy" it doesnt work.

Comment: It seems the code is not accepting "\"..When I replaced \ with * , I get the AD group names.. Any guess why its not taking "\" ?

Comment: @Anjana - Try to escape the \ with another \. So for example your match string would be "t:xxx\\yyy". I'm not sure why you're seeing that behavior, I just created a test group in my environment with the exact same description "t:xxx\yyy" and ran the exact same line of code I posted above and I get my test group returned. Only thing I can think of is your system is processing the \ as an escape character and not a literal \. What version of PowerShell are you running?